# How do I use ajax to get my database information to popup when clicked on certain users table button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been struggling with this issue for about 2 weeks now and I spent more than 15 hours looking for solutions and videos that explain this.

Without any success I decided to ask here for help.

On my website I have displayed users and their statistics in a table. You can see the users Nickname and a few stats and also a "Show more Details button". When clicking on the Details button I want to have a bigger window popup which explains all stats and also the player description of the certain user.

I managed to do this with just using normal form with method get & post. But since I dont want the website to refresh when clicked on the button and getting the popup window to display those two get and post methods was not in any use. I searched and got quickly told that I need to use jQuery and Ajax to get this to work. So I can post information and store it and use it without the site refreshing.

But after a lot of hours of reading and testing out I never getting it to work. And I feel Im just not going to find the solution on my own by just digging for information so I guess the best way is to post here and hope of getting a good answer.

I have looked into this guys video tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK3Nce4SNJs
and they are actually describing what I want to achieve and have on my site. But even though I followed every step and doublechecked multiply times mine still doesn't work so I guess it might be a outdated video.

Index.php file:

```
                if(isset($_GET['NickName'])) {
                  echo '
                <div id="player-information" class="container-player-information">
                    <div class="player-information">
                        <div class="player-info">
                            <div class="player-picture"></div>
                            <p id="NickName" class="player-nick"><img src="png/se.png" alt="Sweden" class="player-country">' . $_GET['NickName'] . '</p>
                            <div class="player-stats">
                                <div class="player-stats-div"><i class="fas fa-medal"></i><p id="ArenaPoints" class="player-stats-text player-arenapoints"></p></div>
                                <div class="player-stats-div"><i class="fas fa-award"></i><p id="KD" class="player-stats-text player-kd"></p></div>
                                <div class="player-stats-div"><i class="fas fa-child"></i><p id="Age" class="player-stats-text player-age"></p></div>
                                <div class="player-stats-div"><i class="fas fa-trophy"></i><p id="Wins" class="player-stats-text player-wins"></p></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="player-description">
                            <p class="player-desc-title">Player Description</p>
                            <p id="Message" class="player-desc"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="player-buttons">
                            <a class="player-button message-player">Contact this user</a>
                            <a class="player-button close-player-information" onclick="closePlayerInfo()">Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '
                         <tr>
                            <td><i class="fas fa-bomb"></i></td>
                            <td><img src="png/se.png" alt="Sweden" class="user-country">' . $row['NickName'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['ArenaPoints'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['Age'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['KD'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['Wins'] . '</td>
                            <td><button class="table-read-more" data-target="#player-information" onclick="showDetails(this)">Details</button></td>

                        </tr>';
function showDetails(button) {
            var NickName = $("#Nick").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "refreshform.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
                "NickName": NickName
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);

                var posts = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#NickName").text(posts.NickName);
                $("#ArenaPoints").text(posts.ArenaPoints);
                $("#Age").text(posts.Age);
                $("#KD").text(posts.KD);
                $("#Wins").text(posts.Wins);
                $("#Message").text(posts.Message);
            });
        })
    }
```

and my **refreshform.php :**

```
<?php

session_start();
require('databas.php');



$NickName = $_POST["NickName"];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE NickName = '$NickName'");

$theInfo = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
echo json_encode($theInfo);

// Show stats for the certain user  

exit();
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, you haven't actually described in detail any real problem, only that _something_ doesn't work - try to include detailed debugging info showing how you've tried to narrow down the issue. If you don't understand how to debug AJAX requests, and PHP/JS in general, then please go and study it, because it's a key skill

Comment: But here's a hint about a likely problem I can see from a quick glance at the code: `method: "GET"` in the AJAX request, but `$_POST["NickName"]` in the PHP...can you see an issue here? Do you understand about HTTP Methods, and the difference between GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc?

Comment: Of course there may be other issues which are not readily apparent from the code. In order to know about those, you'd have to report on any error messages etc that you're getting, and where they occur. But I think that is probably your main issue.